# Simple Login Html, Css Login how to add timer?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've created a simple html, css login I want to add timer

If login x3 failed some text will show can't login need to wait 15 seconds to login again.

```js
var login_attempts = 3;

function check_form() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (name == "admin" && pass == "admin") {
    alert("SuccessFully Logged In");
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
  } else {
    if (login_attempts == 0) {
      alert("No Login Attempts Available");
    } else {
      login_attempts = login_attempts - 1;
      alert("Login Failed Now Only " + login_attempts + " Login Attempts Available");
      if (login_attempts == 0) {
        document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("pass").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("form1").disabled = true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 995px;
}

#form1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 380px;
  margin-left: 305px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #D8D8D8;
}

#form1 p {
  color: #FA8258;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#form1 #login_label {
  color: #FA8258;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#form1 input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

#form1 input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FA8258;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #FE642E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <form id="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return check_form();">
    <p id="login_label">USER LOGIN</p>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT FORM">
    <p>Username : admin Password : admin</p>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Im kinda sure you already asked this with another user earlier today. It does not help to write the same question multiple times with different users.
Also it does not help to write lot's of `........`

Comment: sorry i'm new i've tried to post it without ...... but i won't proceed

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen The first version was a link to an image only. So this is at least a step forward

Comment: @Andreas while I agree the question "quality" has been improved, I dont see the need of switching user

Comment: I assume this just a demo and that you realise a purely client-side login like this doesn't provide any real security?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can extract the disable and call it after 15 seconds using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

I added the message too and use an event listener

```
const toggle = disabled => {
  document.getElementById("message").hidden = !disabled; // toggle the message
  document.getElementById("name").disabled =
  document.getElementById("pass").disabled =
  document.getElementById("form1").disabled = disabled;
  login_attempts = disabled ? 0 : 3; // give more attempts
};
 ...

if (login_attempts == 0) {
  toggle(1); // disable
  setTimeout(toggle, 15000); // called without parameter will enable
}
```

```js
var login_attempts = 3;

const toggle = disabled => {
  document.getElementById("message").hidden = !disabled; // toggle the message
  document.getElementById("name").disabled =
  document.getElementById("pass").disabled =
  document.getElementById("form1").disabled = disabled;
  login_attempts = disabled ? 0 : 3; // give more attempts
};

document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if (name == "admin" && pass == "admin") {
    alert("SuccessFully Logged In");
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("pass").value = "";
  } else {
    if (login_attempts == 0) {
      alert("No Login Attempts Available");
    } else {
      login_attempts = login_attempts - 1;
      alert("Login Failed Now Only " + login_attempts + " Login Attempts Available");
      if (login_attempts == 0) {
        toggle(1); // disable
        setTimeout(toggle, 15000); // called without parameter will enable
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 995px;
}

#form1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 380px;
  margin-left: 305px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #D8D8D8;
}

#form1 p {
  color: #FA8258;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#form1 #login_label {
  color: #FA8258;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#form1 input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

#form1 input[type="submit"] {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FA8258;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #FE642E;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p id="login_label">USER LOGIN</p>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT FORM">
    <p id="message" hidden>Please wait 15 seconds before trying again</p>
    <p>Username : admin Password : admin</p>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: still same sir. i want to lock or if try to login it will show some message or text can't login due to x3 failed login need to wait 15 seconds

Comment: See update. It works now. You get 3 more attempts when it resets

Comment: thank you sir it work now. sorry i'm new to this still trying to explore about html and css